# Deriving a pointer type to the non-pointer class member

Tags: c++

In book named "Using C++" by Rob McGregor there is following example of using pointer-to-member operator

```
class mycls
{
public:
    int member;
    int *ptr;
};

void main()
{
    mycls MyClass;

    // Derive a pointer type to the non-pointer class member
    int mycls::*member = &mycls::member;

    MyClass.ptr = new int;
    mycls* pMyClass = &MyClass;

    pMyClass->*member = 5;
    *MyClass.ptr = 10;

    cout << "pMyClass->*member = " << pMyClass->*member << "\n"; // pMyClass->*member = 5
    cout << "MyClass.*member = " << MyClass.*member << "\n"; // MyClass.*member = 5
    cout << "*MyClass.ptr = " << *MyClass.ptr << "\n"; // *MyClass.ptr = 10
    cout << "*pMyClass->ptr = " << *pMyClass->ptr << "\n"; // *pMyClass->ptr = 10

    delete MyClass.ptr;
}
```

In this example I don't understand why member variable `mycls::member` becomes maybe a pointer after (guessing) this line of code:

```
int mycls::*member = &mycls::member;
```

What this does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you had a local variable:

```
int member;
```

You could make a pointer to it with:

```
int *ptr = &member;
```

To get the pointer to member syntax, we just append `mycls::` in the appropriate places:

```
int mycls::*member = &mycls::member;
```

It might be clearer with an example that shows how the pointer can switch between any members of the class that are of the correct type:

```
class C
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};

void main()
{
    // make pointer to member, initially pointing to a
    int C::*ptrToMember = &C::a;

    C x;
    C *ptrToObj = &x; // make pointer to object x

    ptrToObj->*ptrToMember = 2; // store in a;

    ptrToMember = &C::b; // change pointer to b

    ptrToObj->*ptrToMember = 3; // store in b;
}
```

Note how we create the pointer to the member `a` before we've created an object of type `C`. It's only a pointer to a member, not a pointer to the member of a specific object. In the 'store' steps, we have to say which object as well as which member.

**Update**

In the comments the OP asked if this is the same:

```
int *ptr = &(ptrToObj->a);
```

No, it's not. That is a pointer to any `int`, anywhere in memory.

The easiest way to understand this is to think of what it means technically. A "pointer" is an *absolute* location in memory: where to find an object. A "pointer-to-member" is a *relative* location, sometimes called an offset: where to find an object *within* the storage of an outer object. Internally they are just numbers. A pointer-to-member has to be added to an ordinary pointer to make another pointer.

So if you have a pointer to an object (an `int` is an object!), you can use it to change what is stored at that absolute location in memory:

```
*ptr = 123;
```

But if you have a pointer-to-member, it is not a memory location. It is an offset, an amount to be added to a memory location. You cannot use it by itself. You must "add" it to an object pointer:

```
ptrToObj->*ptrToMember = 132;
```

This means: go to the location in memory `ptrToObj`, then move along by the distance `ptrToMember`.

Comment: Is this also valid and means the same then "int *ptr = &(ptrToObj->a);"

Answer (score 2):

He called the class member `member` and the pointer-to-member `member`, confusing the issue.  Does renaming them like this help?

Class:

```
class SampleClass
{
public:
    int m_data;
    int* m_pointer;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    SampleClass sample;

    // Derive a pointer type to the non-pointer class member
    int SampleClass::*pointerToMember = &SampleClass::m_data;

    sample.m_pointer = new int;
    SampleClass* pSample = &sample;

    pSample->*pointerToMember = 5;
    *sample.m_pointer = 10;

    // pSample->*pointerToMember = 5
    cout << "pSample->*pointerToMember = "
         << pSample->*pointerToMember << "\n";

    // sample.*pointerToMember = 5
    cout << "sample.*pointerToMember = "
         << sample.*pointerToMember << "\n";

    // *sample.m_pointer = 10
    cout << "*sample.m_pointer = "
         << *sample.m_pointer << "\n";

    // *pSample->m_pointer = 10
    cout << "*pSample->m_pointer = "
         << *pSample->m_pointer << "\n";

    delete sample.m_pointer;
}
```

[[Code]](http://codepad.org/eOdokhpK)

Edit: Re "I'm still currious whether `int *ptr = &(ptrToObj->a);` is the same as using pointer to a member like in the book":

It's not a pointer-to-member.  It is just a normal pointer to memory that happens to be in an object.

You can see the syntax in use here:

Class:

```
class C
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    // make pointer to member, initially pointing to a
    int C::*ptrToMember = &C::a;

    C x = {10, 11};
    C *ptrToObj = &x; // make pointer to object x

    cout << "a initial value: " << ptrToObj->*ptrToMember << endl;

    ptrToObj->*ptrToMember = 2; // store in a;

    cout << "a after change: " << ptrToObj->*ptrToMember << endl;

    ptrToMember = &C::b; // change pointer to b

    cout << "b initial value: " << ptrToObj->*ptrToMember << endl;

    ptrToObj->*ptrToMember = 3; // store in b;

    cout << "b after change: " << ptrToObj->*ptrToMember << endl;


    int* ptr = &(ptrToObj->a);
    cout << "ptr to a: " << *ptr << endl;

    ptr = &(ptrToObj->b);
    cout << "ptr to b: " << *ptr << endl;
}
```

[[Code]](http://codepad.org/QxT3AlYe)

Comment: It helps to get a greater understanding of what code does this way, but what what I really didn't understand (now I do thanks to Daniel) is a concept of pointer to class member. I still currious whether "int *ptr = &(ptrToObj->a);" is the same as using pointer to a member like in the book.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk character in the declaration is part of the type.

Your declaration breaks down into

Type: `int mycls::*`

Variable name: `member`

Initialiser: `= &mycls::member`

This new variable `member` points is a member pointer to an int held in a `mycls`. It doesn't have to point to a `mycls::member`.